# Change style of an element when focus is another element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to change the style of a div when focus is on another div.I tried the following code but didn't work

```
<div id="one">
<div id="two">
```

my css file looks like this

```
#one {
    background-color:red;
}
#two:focus #one {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: @FuserThrowError You shouldn't make such radical edits to the code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you mean `:hover` and not `:focus`, then use adjacent selector, using `+` which will select your `#two` on `:hover` of `#one`

```
#one:hover + #two {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8GL/)

> Note: You've a typo, like `if` instead of `id`, also, close your `div`
>   elements.

---

As you commented that you want to use focus on `div`, than replace `:hover` with `:focus` but the adjacent selector logic stays the same...

```
<div id="one" tabindex="1">One, Hover Me</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>

#one:focus + #two {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8GL/1/) *(Press the first line and see the effect) OR (Click on the result window in jsfiddle, and press the tab button once)*

Comment: @SajithNair Yes, why not? :)

Comment: @Alien I was sincerely asking :).

Comment: @SajithNair Adjacent-sibling selectors are supported in Internet Explorer 5.x Macintosh. They are also supported in the Netscape 6 preview release 1 for all the myriad platforms for which it's available, and in preview release 3 of Opera 4 for Windows. There are bugs in the handling of adjacent-sibling selectors in IE5 for Windows, and Opera 3 for Windows. - **From Meyer Web** :)

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but i need :focus and using '+' didn't help

Comment: @maryr CSS cannot go reverse... for that you need to change the HTML in your source, `#two` should come before `#one` and both should be adjacent

Comment: ok thanks for answering... one more case when one is inside another div, say mainone... will the css work then?

Comment: @maryr Yes, than use `>` instead of `+` http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8GL/2/ click on the first line or press tab, just like I explained in the answer :) and you welcome

Comment: no that is not the case... will this work in following css <div id="mainone"> <div id="one"></div> </div> <div id="two"></div>

Comment: @maryr Yea why not? on focus of one, you want to apply to two, than use the `+` selector I provided you in my anwser

Comment: but this didn't work for me 
<div id="main" tabindex="1">
    <div id="one" tabindex="1">One</div>
</div>
<div id="two" tabindex="1">Two</div>

#one:focus + #two {
   color: red;
}  Please correct me if i have done anything wrong..

Comment: @maryr Oh that was in one line so now I got that, nope it wont work like that, as I told you previously, CSS cannot go reverse, so once it enters the element it cannot pop out and select another adjacent element, for using my selector having `+` elements should be side by side and at the same level.. for the markup you provided in comment, you will have to achieve that using JS or jQuery

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery to fix the issue or using hover property in css